# Maven - Generate WAR and JAR separately using same pom.xml

Tags: maven

In my project I need to generate both Jar and WAR file. But the requirement is that both should be able generate separately using different commands.When I run mvn package or maven clean install or any other command both WAR and Jar are getting generated. I am attaching my pom.xml and assembly.xml for reference

pom.xml - http://pastebin.com/6K1rHm6D
assembly.xml - http://pastebin.com/hjJVC5Qr

Comment: Why bother? What's the problem with generating two artifacts with one command?

Comment: Requirement is like Jar should not be created along with WAR as it is not needed everytime.It should be build only when needed.